# Some difficulties to understand a namesapace and his use

Tags: symfony, namespaces, bundles

I haves some difficulties to understand this namespace's use :

```
namespace Utilisateurs\UtilisateursBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User as BaseUser;
```

I have found a namespace called FOS (in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ecommerce/vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle) :

```
namespace FOS\UserBundle;
```

But I don't understand \Entity\User.

This is the code of my Entity :

```
<?php
// src/Acme/UserBundle/Entity/User.php

namespace Utilisateurs\UtilisateursBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="Utilisateurs")
 */
class Utilisateurs extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // your own logic
    }
}
```

When I will understand this namespace, I will be able to fix this problem :

> Fatal error: Class 'FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User' not found in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ecommerce/src/Utilisateurs/UtilisateursBundle/Entity/Utilisateurs.php on line 14
>   [2015-08-16 17:19:57] php.CRITICAL: Fatal Error: Class 'FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User' not found {"type":1,"file":"/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ecommerce/src/Utilisateurs/UtilisateursBundle/Entity/Utilisateurs.php","line":14,"level":-1,"stack":[]}
>
> Fatal error: Class 'FOS\UserBundle\Propel\om\BaseUser' not found in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ecommerce/vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/Propel/User.php
>   on line 18

Comment: `use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;`

Comment: It's working, thank you, but I dont' understand why...

Comment: Because the class `User` exist in folder `/vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/Model` in file `User.php`. Namespace `FOS\UserBundle` point to folder `/vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/`.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to watch [PHP namespaces in 120 seconds](http://knpuniversity.com/screencast/php-namespaces-in-120-seconds) screencast.